# Redirect to Page from within another thread in a shared method

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, redirect, asynchronous

I am developing an ASP.NET web application that communicates to another application asynchronously.

In webform1 I call `MyClass.Connect`. At some point in the future I get a response from the object.

When I get my response I want to display a page telling the user about the response but I can't just do `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect` because the `HttpContext` is nothing.

Here is a snippet of the class

```
Public Class MyClass
    Private Shared WithEvents _remClient As New RemoteClient

    Public Sub Connect
        _remClient.ConnectToServer
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub _remClient_ClientConnected() Handles _remClient.ClientConnected
        'I want to do a redirect here - how?
    End Sub

End Class
```

Can someone give me an idea of how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This redirect must be done on browser using javascript.

Send as return a flag for redirect, and the url, where to go and then set:

```
   if(flagForRefirect)   
    window.location = WhereToGoPage;
```

Comment: This is an asynchronous operation though so there is no return

Comment: @MattWilko If there is not return, and not connection to the page, how to you make it redirect ? you simple can not.

Comment: In the end I implemented something similar to this but it waits for the asynchronous call to come back (or time out) in the page before redirecting to the appropriate page